# mouse and keyboard unresponsive OR black screen

Tags: input-devices

I'm very new to Kubuntu. After several attempts I was able to finally install Kubuntu successfully. After the reboot,  I got to the login screen. Nothing unusual until I login when the mouse and keyboard do not work at all. The lights are still up though.

I tried a reboot and logged back in. Now i have a black screen with some of the elements of the desktop showing up.

I saw similar threads with commands to run to download additional drivers but I could not figure out for the life of me how to pull up the command line before or during the login screen.

Comment: I left the black screen on for 5 min while I was starting this thread. I realized that the mouse and keyboard are working but are too slow to reapond. I just saw the context menu when one would right click at the desktop.

Comment: What is your hardware?

Comment: Mobo:  emaxx emx-mcp61d3-icafe; CPU: amd athlon x3 455; Ram: 4 GB;  HD: 80 GB;

Comment: I downloaded and installed 14.04 64 bit.

Comment: What is video adapter?

Comment: Im jus using the onboard video.

Comment: And what is the onboard video?

Comment: Im sorry @pilot6 Im not much of a help. I dont have my mobo's docs anymore.  This is what i can find online: http://www.game-debate.com/motherboard/index.php?mot_id=1066&motherboard=Emaxx%20EMX-MCP61D3-iCafe

Answer (score 1):

I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it/162076#162076) and i was able to boot up to a responsive system. I was prompted to install nvidia driver and it is now in progress.

For all it is worth, i think this is the biggest stride of a progress that i had made in the last 12 hours.

Comment: Im happy to report that i have a running system now. Thank you pilot6 for keeping up with me.  I really appreciate your time.